# Bias and variance calculation for Ridge estimator of β

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, multicollinearity, bias, ridge-regression

I understand how bias and variance for ridge estimator of β are calculated when the model is **Y**=**X**β + ϵ. But I have the model **Y**=**X**<sup>t</sup>β + ϵ. I don't understand if a model like that makes sense, can someone help me with that? If it does, how to derive the bias and variance for ridge estimator of β?

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot imagine that the difference between the two models amounts to more than just notation.

Comment: I don't know if that makes sense since in the usual Y=Xβ + ϵ model, Y is _n x 1_ matrix, X is _n x k_ matrix, β is _k x 1_ matrix. If X is transposed, then X^t is _k x n_, on the other hand β is _k x 1_. How can they even multiply, then give Y as a result, which is _n x 1_.

Comment: That is in principle correct, but without seeing the specific reference you deal with, that will be hard to answer. It might just be the case that, unusually, $X$ is defined as $k\times n$ in the second case.

Comment: Yeah, that actually can be the case. Thanks!